# Find the best set among the many sets based on it's item's cost

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have items in sets as a below example. Each item contains particular cost.
I have a max budget. I need to do combination in such a way that in each combination I need at least one item from each set and sum of the costs should be equal to my budget.

Example

```
A = [a1, a2, a3, a4, ... , a10]
B = [b1, b2, b3, b4, ... , b10]
C = [c1, c2, c3, c4, ... , c10] may be upto G

Max budget = 10
cost of a1 = 2
        a2 = 8
        b1 = 1
        b2 = 7
        c1 = 3
        c2 = 1
        etc
```

Output can be

```
[a1, b2, c2] i,e 2+7+1 = 10
[a2, b1, c2] i,e 8+1+1 = 10
[a1, b1, c1] i,e 2+1+3 = 6 Eliminated (since 6 != 10)
goes on
```

I can have max of `7 sets` and `10 items` in each. So maximum combinations will be `10^7`. Is there any algorithm to achieve this easily. I followed brute force method and it is too expensive.
Thank you.

Comment: It's probably np-hard. A natural and powerful way would be using *mixed-integer-programming*.

Comment: Really? Sounds like `10^7` can be bruteforced in a second. Do you need it real-time?